# Should I ask for a referral from new LinkedIn connections?

Tags: linkedin, referral

I recently moved to a new city and have connected with multiple people there through LinkedIn (I sent them a note telling them that I just moved there and would like to expand my professional network). They accepted my invites but no conversations were made so far.

There's this job that I'd like to apply and one of my new connections happens to be one of the HR managers there. Is there any tactful way that I could ask for a referral from that connection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Do Not** ask them for a referral.

What are you expecting them to tell about you when they never worked with you under professional settings?

The only thing they know is that you added them on LinkedIn with some public information that you wrote about yourself.

If you approach me for a referral this way, I would raise a flag and would make me question all your other referrals you included in the application.

I would, instead of asking them for a referral, just contact them and show some interest in the job they have, and furthermore ask for advises and recommendation on how to apply. In simple words, **start the network with them**.

Comment: Exactly. A referral or recommendation implies the person you're asking has some value basis to refer you on: "I just added them on LinkedIn" doesn't really hold any value.

Comment: Agreed and +1.  I always got a kick out of my mom's friends endorsing me for SQL Server when the last time they saw me I was in high school.

Comment: Spot on answer!!